# how to add semantic ui in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

i want to add semantic-ui to rails and also i dont want to use ready gems.
i already install it in a semantic folder in beside other rails and build it via gulp. 
then i copy semantic.css to asset stylesheet and require it in application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     *=require semantic.css
```

and link it in application.html.erb but it doesnot work properly.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="semantic.css">
```

so i think i should know a lot more about adding semantic ui to a rails app.
is there any document or instruction or any help.
there is also a same question by others but since 4 month ago it is not answered
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [SASS version](https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass) that's a bit faster in terms of page loads.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the `semantic-ui` to the rails asset pipe line. for this you can use the gem [less-rails-semantic_ui](https://github.com/maxd/less-rails-semantic_ui)