# Setting up Semantic UI for Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I am following the suggestion from [Rails and Semantic UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909653/how-to-add-semantic-ui-in-a-rails-app) to use Semantic UI using the [less-rails-semantic_ui](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Rails-LESS) gem.

The documentation on installing into an existing Rails project from [less-rails-semantic_ui][3] is:

1. Add gems `less-rails-semantic_ui` and `autoprefixer-rails` to Gemfile
2. Execute `bundle install`
3. Execute `rails generate semantic_ui:install`
4. Require semantic_ui/semantic_ui.js in app/assets/application.js:
   //= require semantic_ui/semantic_ui
5. Require semantic_ui/semantic_ui.css in app/assets/application.css:
   *= require semantic_ui/semantic_ui

However after these steps, using classes from Semantic in views, eg. on buttons, does not change the visual appearence. Eg. with a simple `new.html.erb`

```html
<div class="ui three  buttons">                                                                                                            
  <button class="ui active button">One</button>                                    
  <button class="ui button">Two</button>                                           
  <button class="ui button">Three</button>                                         
</div>
```

three plain buttons are rendered.

What are the missing steps I need to do to use semantic?

Comment: Are apllication.js/.css being loaded in you application layout?

Comment: Deleting and rescaffolding the basic rails project structure and repeating the above steps made it work,